# why am I getting this bash scripting for loop error?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
a=1
for [ $a -ge 1 ]
do
        touch ~/file.$a
        a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

When I execute it it gives me below error

./script.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$a'

./script.sh: line 3: `for [ $a -ge 1 ]'

But it works fine when using "while" instead of "for".

Could you please help me understand why it works with while loop and not with for loop?

Thanks

Comment: For loops have a different syntax. This is just wrong.

Comment: Don't invent your own syntax. Have a look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bash-scripting-for-loop/) to see how to write a loop.

Answer (score 0):

for loop syntax is not like that mate, do this instead.

```
for a in {1..10}
do
touch /file.$a
done
```

you need to declare the range of the variable first.

Answer (score 0):

You meant to use `while` not `for` in that syntax.  Also since you're using bash, use a `for (( ))` loop:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= 10; ++i )); do
    ...
done
```

The loop by brace expansion has also been suggested in the other answer but I'm not a fan of it since it expands iteration values to words before looping.